# Change ViewController based on IF statement

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I need to learn how to go to a different viewcontroller based on an if statement. I'm totally new to swift. I have this already - when the counter gets to 5, I need it to go to a different view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var countNumber: UILabel!

    var conta = 0


    @IBAction func counterPlus(sender: AnyObject) {

        conta++


        if conta == 5{

         //I WANT TO GO TO A DIFFERENT VIEWCONTROLLER HERE


        }else

        {
            countNumber.text = String(conta)
        }


    }
```

Comment: and why don't you push that _different view-controller_ into the navigation stack if you want it? I don't understand your issue here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in a way of a segue, or with storyboard identifiers.
Use the following code:

```
// segue method, also give your segue an identifier in storyboard

if // your statement {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier")
}

// storyboard identifier method, give your view controller an identifier in storyboard in the "identity inspector"

if // your statement {
    let destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier")
    presentViewController(destinationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: //Created a segue (right drag VC1 to VC2) Identifier “segueOne”)  

if conta == 5{  
    performSegueWithIdentifier(“segueOne”)  
} // error: Type (String?, sender AnyObject?) does not conform to protocol ‘StringLiteralConvertible’

//VC2 class ‘SecondViewController’(Module changeViewController)

if conta == 5{
    let destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“SecondViewController”)
    presentViewController(destinationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} // error: ’UIStoryboard? does not have a member named ‘instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier’

Comment: @ClaudioBarrozoPrado Please send me the code on Pastebin or send me an image of the code, I can't really understand like that

Comment: It worked with  performSegueWithIdentifier("segueOne", sender: nil) // sender: nil was missing

Answer (score 0):

Worked with

if // your statement {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("segueOne", sender: nil)

}